# find all duplicates on an array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have the following array of objects:

```
[
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example3' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example4' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example5' }
]
```

and i want to put colors on them if they have the same `ip` but not equal `name`, so something like this.

```
[
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel', color: '' },
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel', color: '' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example3', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example4', color: 'black' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example5', color: 'black' }
]
```

how can you achieve this using lodash? or vanilla?

---

edit: i tried to code it, but it producing different output.

```
[
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example2', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 202.164.171.184, name: 'example3', color: 'red' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example4', color: 'black' },
 { ip: 127.0.0.1, name: 'example5', color: 'black' }
]
```

here's my code.

```
      let list = _.groupBy(data, 'ip')
      const colorList = ['pink', 'blue', 'pink', 'red']
      let logsList = []

      _.keys(list).forEach(key => {
        const color = colorList[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorList.length)]

        if (Array.isArray(list[key])) {
          list[key].forEach(data => {
            data.color = color
            logsList.push(data)
          })
        }
      })
```

Comment: How did you attempt to solve this?

Comment: `Array.isArray(list[key])` <= this check shouldn't be necessary.  The result of a groupBy should always result in each key pointing to an array of elements, even if there is just one element.

Comment: It looks like your primary thing that is missing is that you are not checking to see if the names are different.  You are just putting colors on things.

Comment: what is wrong with your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using *every* to check and see if the name and ip are the same in every element of list[key] before setting the color:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#every

```js
let data = [
 { ip: '1', name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: '1', name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example3' },
 { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example4' },
 { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example5' }
];

let list = _.groupBy(data, 'ip')
const colorList = ['pink', 'blue', 'pink', 'red']
let logsList = []

console.log('list: ' + JSON.stringify(list));

_.keys(list).forEach(key => {
  if (Array.isArray(list[key])) {
    let color = '';
    if(!_.every(list[key], list[key][0])) {
      color = colorList[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorList.length)]
    }

  
    list[key].forEach(data => {
      data.color = color
      logsList.push(data)
    })
  }
})

console.log('logsList: ' + JSON.stringify(logsList));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems in your code

One problem can be in generating random colors: you can get on color twice

Fixed code:

```js
let data = [ // Example data
  { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
  { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
  { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
  { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
  { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example3' },
  { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example4' },
  { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example5' }
];

let list = _.groupBy(data, 'ip')

const colorList = ['pink', 'blue', 'red'] // Color should not be in this list twice!

let logsList = []

_.keys(list).forEach(key => {
  if(!colorList.length) throw new Error('Not enough colors');

  let color = colorList[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorList.length)] // Chose color
  colorList.splice(colorList.indexOf(color), 1); // Remove chosen color from the list
                                                 // So, we cannot chos one color twice
  
  // Removed not-needed IF
  list[key].forEach(data => {   
    data.color = color
    logsList.push(data)
  })
})

console.log(logsList)
```

```html
<!-- Get lodash -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

### Another working solution

Not using Lodash, written while your code was not added to question. Sad to delete.

```js
let datas = [
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: 1, name: 'examplel' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example2' },
 { ip: '202.164.171.184', name: 'example3' },
 { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example4' },
 { ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'example5' }
];

let colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'purple', /* And some more... */]; // Colors for diffrent IP's

let currentColor = 0, // Which color we are currently using - index in colors[]
    pastIp = null;    // Past Ip

let colored = datas.sort((a, b) => ('' + a.ip).localeCompare(b.ip)) // Sort IP's,
                                                                    // Same adresses will be grouped 
                   .map(i => {
                     if(pastIp && i.ip != pastIp) currentColor++; // We have started colorig another IP (as example, past was 1.1.1.1, this is 2.2.2.2)
                     // Else, we are looping same IP's (as example, past was 1.1.1.1, this is also 1.1.1.1)
                     pastIp = i.ip; // Current will be past
                     return {color: colors[currentColor], ...i}; // Add color property
                   })

console.log(colored); // Do somethig with result
```